# Rails friendly forward redirect loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, session, redirect, controller

I have a controller action that creates a guest user.  For some reason, when you click the guest sign-in link, I get a redirect loop issue (not all the time, but sometimes) upon trying to forward the user back to the previous page.  Here's my code:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :remember_location

  protected

  def remember_location
    session[:return_to] = request.referrer
  end

  def redirect_back_or(default)
    redirect_to(session[:return_to] || default)
    clear_return_to
  end

  def clear_return_to
    session.delete(:return_to)
  end
end

class GuestUsersController < ApplicationController

  def create
    # do create thing...
    redirect_back_or(root_url)
  end

end
```

Seems like it should work.  Any ideas what might be causing the issue?  Troubleshooting tips would be helpful as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not "remember" the `create` action on your `GuestUsersController`. Add this to the top of that class.

```
skip_before_filter :remember_location, only: [ :create ]
```

Comment: other part to this solution then is that i need to: session[:return_to] = request.fullpath instead of session[:return_to] = request.referrer